# Google Sheets offline time stamp?

Tags: google-sheets, offline

I have a sheet in Google Sheets that uses a bit of code:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() <= 2 && r.getRow() >= 8 ) { // first row for SAR#, second for last name (i.e. for folks without a SAR#)
      var timeCell = s.getRange(r.getRow(),4)
      if( timeCell.getValue() === '' && r.getValue() != '' ) // date is empty but last name is not
        timeCell.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"HHmm"))
    }
  }
}
```

(thanks to whoever made the post that I adapted this code from - sorry I lost the link)

The question is: how can I duplicate this behavior in Google Sheets while offline?

I noticed that Sheets offline (using the android Google Sheets app) has these features:

- formulas work as normal
- references to other sheets in the same spreadsheet work as normal
- references to external spreadsheets don't work  (i.e. IMPORTRANGE)
- scripts don't work

Of these, only the last one (scripts don't work) is a show-stopper; we are fine without external references in this case.

None of those features are surprising, but, I'm wondering if there's a way to duplicate the timestamp functionality while offline - perhaps using some formula wizardry, or by any other means?

Comment: There is no way to replicate the functionality of this script with formulas. By the way, scripts work in the Android app, if there is Internet connection (they are executed on Google's servers).